# Is it safe to execute cron jobs from the root account?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

Is it safe to execute cron jobs from the root account?

(the job is supposed to send log files via email)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as safe as running anything else as root.  If you know that he script you are running is safe, or if it absolutely requires root privileges (preferably both conditions should be true), then run it as root.  Otherwise, run it as a task-specific user (database user, backup user, etc) with the appropriate permissions.